# Multiple Variable Variables in PHP

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and programming in general...  I am attempting to use a foreach loop to set some options on a page I have created.  It all works except for the last section, where I am attempting to assign variables dynamically, so I can use them outside the loop.

```
<?PHP

$array=array(foo, bar, baz);

foreach ($array as $option) {

  // I have if statements to determine what $option_req 
  // and $option_status end up being, they work correctly.

  $option_req="Hello";
  $option_status="World";

  $rh='Req_';
  $sh='Status_';

  $$rh.$$option=$option_req;
  $$sh.$$option=$option_status;

  }

echo "<br>R_Foo: ".$Req_foo;
echo "<br>S_Foo: ".$Status_foo;
echo "<br>R_Bar: ".$Req_bar;
echo "<br>S_Bar: ".$Status_bar;
echo "<br>R_Baz: ".$Req_baz;
echo "<br>S_Baz: ".$Status_baz;

?>
```

When the loop is finished, should this now give me six variables?

```
$Req_foo
$Status_foo

$Req_bar
$Status_bar

$Req_baz
$Status_baz
```

I have played with this a bit, searches on Google seem fruitless today.

Comment: For all that is holy, please don't do it like this.

Comment: maybe if you add your whole code it will make more sense... what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PHP doesn't like the concatenation when you're trying to do an assignment. Try doing so beforehand, like so:

```
<?php

$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

foreach ($array as $option) 
{
    $option_req="Hello";
    $option_status="World";

    $rh = 'Req_';
    $sh = 'Status_';

    $r_opt = $rh.$option;
    $s_opt = $sh.$option;

    $$r_opt = $option_req;
    $$s_opt = $option_status;
}

echo "<br>R_Foo: ".$Req_foo;
echo "<br>S_Foo: ".$Status_foo;
echo "<br>R_Bar: ".$Req_bar;
echo "<br>S_Bar: ".$Status_bar;
echo "<br>R_Baz: ".$Req_baz;
echo "<br>S_Baz: ".$Status_baz;
```

As other commenters suggested, this isn't a great practice. Try storing your data in an array, rather than just cluttering up your namespace with variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The example works... After seeing this example "variable variables" clicked for me.  That, and an array example above just gave me a better idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

To access some array item, just access some array item.
No loops required.

```
$req = array("foo" => 1, 
             "bar" => 2, 
             "baz" => 3,
             );
echo $req['foo'];
```

plain and simple

Comment: Thanks.  I've always assigned arrays that just use the default numbers [0],[1], etc.  Giving array elements names makes this much easier to reference!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* (though you should not!) do:

```
${$rh.$option} = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables don't work that way.  You need to have one variable containing the string.

```
$opt_r = $rh.$option;
$$opt_r = $option_req;

$opt_s = $sh.$option;
$$opt_s = $option_status;
```

Also, make sure to quote your strings:

```
$array=array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

I don't suggest using variable variables, but if you want to, this is how to do it.